# Working Application Stops Working With 'Main Class Not Found On'. No Changes have been made

Tags: java, netbeans, program-entry-point

I have an application (written about 10 years ago by someone else who is retired) that resides on a Stand-Alone Windows XP PC.

It was devleoped using NetBeans (Currently we have 6.9 installed on the PC) and controls a testbench for running component testing.

The application, initiated by a batch file on the desktop, has functioned perfectly well for Approximately 10 years.

However, 2 days ago it just stopped working with a message

'File Not Found' with the correct path and filename to a Config File that resides in a directory on the PC. This file exists.

I tried to run the application from the Dos command line (in the DIST ribution directory) using

```
Java -jar “AdBlue.jar”
```

This resulted in an error message being returned

> 'Exception In Thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError ..... Could Not Find The Main Class"

No changes have been made to the PC.

It is the same Operating system (Windows XP - Shortly To Be Upgraded)
The java version has not been changed
The application has not been changed
The config file is still in the same directory
The permissions on the Config file have not been changed

I have checked Properties/Run and 'AdBlue.Main' is selected.

I am at a loss.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me (Someone who has not used java and Netbeans before) in the right direction. The test bench has come to a stand still and it will affect out production line shortly

Comment: For clarification: Is your command precisely as shown in the question: `Java -jar “AdBlue.jar”` - with uppercase `J` and curly quotes? Or is it actually this: `java -jar "AdBlue.jar"` (lowercase `j` and straight quotes)?

Comment: [1] Submit **java -version** from the command line, and then update your question with the output that is displayed. [2] Also, if possible, can you display the **bat** file that is run from the command line?

Comment: Also, please post the full error message and any accompanying stack trace when you got the **UnsupportedClassVersionError** message. Or was the error message shown in your question the only output?

Answer (score 0):

We have found that teh file being searched for is corrupt.
It has been recreated and appears to have solved the problem

Thanks for all of the replies

Kind regards

Iain